# Transactions issue with Slick 3.0

Tags: transactions, slick, slick-3.0

Have a a few tables into slick. Read data from them and send to the remote API. Remote API can send response with 'error' or 'ok' status.

How in the correct way can I lock tables ROW and roll-back data into table if remote API send response 'error'

BR!

Comment: What do you want to roll back, if you only **read** data from your database?